# Передача параметров между прототипами

Tags: javascript

```
Constr.prototype.one = function(){

}

Constr.prototype.two = function(){
var param = 34;
}
```

Можно ли передать переменную param с прототипа two в прототип one?

Comment: вообще у меня такая ситуация что после срабатывания прототипа one, должна вызваться функция, которая будет снова вызывать прототип one но уже с параметрами

Comment: искусственный вопрос даст такой же искусственный ответ: в данном случае к `param` есть доступ **только** внутри функции `two`.

Comment: Попробуй отредактировать вопрос, добавив больше подробностей, что конкретно ты хочешь сделать

Comment: я хочу чтобы при вызове функции two, сработала функция one в которую был бы передан параметр param

Comment: что мешает вызвать функцию one передав ей параметр? :-)

Comment: в one нельзя передавать параметры, потому что код ломается)

Comment: её можно вызвать только как ссылку elem.click(obj.one).

Comment: хотел:
 elem.click(function(){
var param = 34;
one(parem);

})
но не получается

Comment: а у меня не ломается :-)

Comment: Значит на смотреть что у тебя за код :-) Отредактировать вопрос ты можешь с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: у меня просто большой проект, а я нуб. ))

Comment: пока закрыл как дубликат, добавь необходимую информацию в вопрос и, возможно, переоткроем.